# Asking for Big Query code for the below mentioned SAS-SQL code

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, sas

Suppose I have a table name customer which is having cust_id(customer ID) and purchase date columns. I need to know the Big query code of below mentioned SAS-SQL code.

```
proc sql;
select * from customer 
where cust_id <>. ;
quit;
```

What would be the Big query code (specifically 3rd line of the code)
of this piece of code?

Comment: Hi @tanmoy bhattacharya,  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the following:

```
select * 
from customer 
where cust_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In SAS SQL,  period(.) is used to define missing values which are equal to null and <> denotes not equal if used with WHERE statement. For your requirement, a BigQuery [IS operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#is_operators)  can be used. The third statement can be written with IS NOT NULL. You can try the query below.

```
SELECT * FROM
 `project.dataset.customer`
WHERE cust_id IS NOT NULL
```